# Table view with button that changes label based on user input

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to create a table view with just 1 label and 1 button in the prototype cell.

When you click the button, it asks the user for text input, and then replaces the label in the same cell with that text. I have been able to create a version of this where pressing the button updates the corresponding label with pre-determined text, but not input text.

The problems are:

(a) Can't seem to run an alert asking for user input in the `TableViewCell` class I created - must be in the `ViewController` to do that it seems?

(b) Have set up a `TableCellDelegate` protocol, and can detect a button press, then pass back to the ViewController to run the alert, but can't find a way to send the text input back to the `TableViewCell` to be updated.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the ViewController code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}

extension ViewController: TableCellDelegate {
    func didTapButton(label: String) {
        print(label)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell") as! TableViewCell
        let label = "Label " + String(indexPath.row)
        cell.setLabel(label: label)
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
}
```

And here is the TableViewCell (without the alert coding):

```
import UIKit

protocol TableCellDelegate {
    func didTapButton (label: String)
}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableCellLabel: UILabel!

    var delegate: TableCellDelegate?
    func setLabel(label: String) {
        tableCellLabel.text = label
    }

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
       delegate?.didTapButton(label: tableCellLabel.text!)
       tableCellLabel.text = "pressed"
    }
}
```

Finally, here is the alert code I am trying to insert in place of the `tableCellLabel.text = "pressed"` code above:

```
        // Create the alert window
        let buttonAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Label", message: "Enter Label", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        // Add text input field to alert controller
        buttonAlert.addTextField { (buttonLabel:UITextField!) -> Void in
            buttonLabel.placeholder = "Enter Label"
        }

        // Create alert action for OK button
        let okButtonAction = UIAlertAction.init(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (alert:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

            // Get the button name from the alert text field
            let buttonLabel = buttonAlert.textFields![0]
            let buttonLabelString = buttonLabel.text
            self.tableCellLabel.text = buttonLabelString

            // Dismiss alert if ok pressed
            buttonAlert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        // Add ok Button alert actions to alert controller
        buttonAlert.addAction(okButtonAction)

        // Create alert action for a cancel button
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel) { (alert:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

            // Dismiss alert if cancel pressed
            buttonAlert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        // Add Cancel Button alert actions to alert controller
        buttonAlert.addAction(cancelAction)

        // Display the alert window
        self.present(buttonAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Where this goes wrong is the `self.present(buttonAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)`, which it doesn't appear you can call from a table cell.

Comment: Add a UITextField to the tableview cell or look up UIAlertController with text input

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you have the `UItableview` set up, it sounds like you're going to want to take the id of the data of the cell that is registering the alert and then updating the button text in that cell based on that within the table view render statement. Remember that setting the label of a button has an animation, it **can** cause some odd things to happen if you're animating other things at the same time.

You'll probably want to look at reload rows in the link below in your table view. Be careful though, the `indexPath` is not always the same as when the user interaction is called if you're using `dequeueReusableCell`. 
[UITableView Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614862-reloaddata)

See [UIButton Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624018-settitle) for swift implementation, you'll have to set it for the current state of the button.

Comment: I realize I should add example code, I'll add later if I have time.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code example? I’d like to see what you’re working with.

Comment: @Marc It looks like you updated your progress, is the code current with your progress of being able to update the button name with predetermined text?

Comment: Yes the code in the first 2 sections works as all it does is replace the button name with 'pressed'. However, when I try to replace that command with the code in the 3rd section, to request user input, I get the error that there is no 'present' member in the TableViewCell.

Comment: You could create a delegate function on the TVC and set that function within the tableview controller.
In the cell class, action outlet for the button:
    `public var cell_tapped = {}
    @IBAction func tapped_cell(_ sender: Any) {
        cell_tapped()
    }`

TableView Code:
    `cell.cell_tapped = { self.tapped_cell(at: index) }`

Then tapped_cell is a function declared in the view controller, it will give you index context as well.